# ceph storage MDSs report slow metadata IOs

Tags: linux, storage, ceph

I am playing with ceph storage in lab and i have single server so thought installing all service on single box, like MON, OSD, MDS etc.

I have create two disk using loopdevice  (This server has SSDs disk so speed is really good)

```
root@ceph2# losetup -a
/dev/loop1: [64769]:26869770 (/root/100G-2.img)
/dev/loop0: [64769]:26869769 (/root/100G-1.img)
```

This is how my `ceph -s` output looks

```
root@ceph2# ceph -s
  cluster:
    id:     1106ae5c-e5bf-4316-8185-3e559d246ac5
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            1 MDSs report slow metadata IOs
            Reduced data availability: 65 pgs inactive
            Degraded data redundancy: 65 pgs undersized

  services:
    mon: 1 daemons, quorum ceph2 (age 8m)
    mgr: ceph2(active, since 9m)
    mds: 1/1 daemons up
    osd: 2 osds: 2 up (since 20m), 2 in (since 38m)

  data:
    volumes: 1/1 healthy
    pools:   3 pools, 65 pgs
    objects: 0 objects, 0 B
    usage:   11 MiB used, 198 GiB / 198 GiB avail
    pgs:     100.000% pgs not active
             65 undersized+peered
```

Don't know from where that MDS slow IO error coming from and mds stat stuck at creating

```
root@ceph2# ceph mds stat
cephfs:1 {0=ceph2=up:creating}
```

This is what health detail look like

```
root@ceph2# ceph health detail
HEALTH_WARN 1 MDSs report slow metadata IOs; Reduced data availability: 65 pgs inactive; Degraded data redundancy: 65 pgs undersized
[WRN] MDS_SLOW_METADATA_IO: 1 MDSs report slow metadata IOs
    mds.ceph2(mds.0): 31 slow metadata IOs are blocked > 30 secs, oldest blocked for 864 secs
[WRN] PG_AVAILABILITY: Reduced data availability: 65 pgs inactive
    pg 1.0 is stuck inactive for 22m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.0 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.1 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.2 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.3 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.4 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.5 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.6 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.7 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.8 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.c is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.d is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.e is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.f is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.10 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.11 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.12 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.13 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.14 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.15 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.16 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.17 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.18 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.19 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.1a is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.1b is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.0 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.1 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.2 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.3 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.4 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.5 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.6 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.7 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.9 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.c is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.d is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.e is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.f is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.10 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.11 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.12 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.13 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.14 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.15 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.16 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.17 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.18 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.19 is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.1a is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.1b is stuck inactive for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
[WRN] PG_DEGRADED: Degraded data redundancy: 65 pgs undersized
    pg 1.0 is stuck undersized for 22m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.0 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.1 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.2 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.3 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.4 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.5 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.6 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.7 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.8 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.c is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.d is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.e is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.f is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.10 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.11 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.12 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.13 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.14 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.15 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.16 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.17 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 2.18 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.19 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.1a is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 2.1b is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.0 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.1 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.2 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.3 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.4 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.5 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.6 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.7 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.9 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.c is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.d is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.e is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.f is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.10 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.11 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.12 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.13 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.14 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.15 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.16 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.17 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
    pg 3.18 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.19 is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.1a is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [1]
    pg 3.1b is stuck undersized for 14m, current state undersized+peered, last acting [0]
```

What would be wrong here? Do you think this is because i have single server and 2 OSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MDS reports slow metadata because it can't contact any PGs, all your PGs are "inactive". As soon as you bring up the PGs the warning will go away eventually. The default crush rule has a size 3 for each pool, if you only have two OSDs this can never be achieved. You'll also have to change the `osd_crush_chooseleaf_type` to 0 so OSD is your crush failure domain instead of host. Then you should also change the pool size to 2 so all PGs fit onto both OSDs. But be aware that a pool size of 2 is only for testing purposes or if you don't value your data, it's not recommended for any production use.

Comment: “crush_chooseleaf_type” did magic, i figured that out few days ago but was waiting for someone to reply so I can accept. Thank you!